# Set date modified of all .DS_Store files in a folder and all its subfolders via terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, sudo, touch, .ds-store

I'm on macOS Sierra. I'd ***really*** love to know how to use terminal to set the date modified of all .DS_Store files in a specific hierarchy to a given date.

So far, I know that I can do this:

```
sudo touch -t 200001010101 ./.DS_Store
```

That will set the date modified of the .DS_Store file in the current directory to 01/01/2000 01:01 AM. But I need to find a way to do this not just for the current directory, but ***all subfolders*** within that directory as well.

I seriously hope there is a simple solution for this. I'm sick to death of the date modified of various folders on my system being changed simply because of view changes I make in Finder when browsing them!

This question is about a smaller part of a larger task I'm trying to accomplish. I've almost got it all working now except part of the script that only seems to work when I run it from terminal directly. Here's a link to the main issue in case anyone reading this might be able to help: [Service to execute series of commands on selected folders to eliminate issues with .DS_Store files in Finder](https://superuser.com/questions/1732814/service-to-execute-series-of-commands-on-selected-folders-to-eliminate-issues-wi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `bash` you can try something like:

```
sudo touch -t 200001010101 **/.DS_Store
```

This command will change the timestamp of `.DS_Store` in all subdirectories

More universal way is to use command like:

```
find . -name .DS_Store -type -f -exec touch -t 200001010101 {} \;
```

P.S. You may need to set this `shopt -s dotglob` if it's not already set.

Comment: Is there any way to make this recursive to *all* subdirectories within the current directory? After executing this command, I noticed that the .DS_Store files in subdirectories deeper than the directories within the current directory still retained their current modification date.

Comment: @MikMak, check my edited answer

Comment: For bash, you would need to do a `shopt -s dotglob` to make `**` work. In zsh, the command would run like this without the need to set something.